# CNN doesn't learn simple geometric patterns

Tags: caffe

It must be a very stupid question, but since I have not such sufficient know ledge storage and having no more time to search the answer of it, I have to put it here to ask for help. I generated a training dataset of images of simple geometric shapes as triangles, squares, diamonds etc. by programs and constructed a CNN with two convolutional layers and one pooling layer also a final fully connected layer to learn the classifications of these shapes. But the network just does not to learn it. I mean the loss just does not decrease. What is the cause?

In Caffe, the neural network configuration file "very_simple_one.prototxt" looks like:

```
name: "very_simple_one"
layer {
  ##name: "input"
  name: "data"
  ##type: "Input"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  transform_param {
    mean_file: "images/train_valid_lmdb_mean.binaryproto"
  }
  data_param {
    source: "images/train_valid_lmdb"
    batch_size: 1000
    backend: LMDB
  }
  input_param {
    shape {
      dim: 1
      dim: 3
      dim: 200
      dim: 200
    }
  }
}
layer {
  ##name: "input"
  name: "data"
  ##type: "Input"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  transform_param {
    mean_file: "images/train_valid_lmdb_mean.binaryproto"
  }
  data_param {
    source: "images/test_lmdb"
    batch_size: 100
    backend: LMDB
  }
  input_param {
    shape {
      dim: 1
      dim: 3
      dim: 200
      dim: 200
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 50
    kernel_size: 5
    stride: 5
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "conv1"
}
layer {
  name: "pool1"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "pool1"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 5
    stride: 5
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool1"
  top: "conv2"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 3
    kernel_size: 8
    stride: 8
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu2"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "conv2"
}
layer {
  name: "fc3"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "fc3"
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 3
  }
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "fc3"
  bottom: "label"
}
```

The "solver.prototxt" looks like:

```
net: "very_simple_one.prototxt"
type: "SGD"
test_iter: 15
test_interval: 100
base_lr: 0.05
lr_policy: "step"
gamma: 0.9999
stepsize: 100
display: 20
max_iter: 50000
snapshot: 2000
momentum: 0.9
weight_decay: 0.00000000000
solver_mode: GPU
```

Also tried AdaGrad by commenting the "momentum" and modify the "type" to AdaGrad.
Train this net by the command:

```
....../caffe/build/tools/caffe train -solver solver.prototxt
```

All failed to train. I mean the loss just does not decrease. The loss is hovering within a very very small interval but never really to decrease.

Just wonder if the dataset is definitely not able to be trained or there is something wrong with my configuration files, the above ones?

I also have modified the network according to what Ibrahim Yousuf said by replacing the pooling layer as convolutional layer as:

```
name: "very_simple_one"
layer {
  ##name: "input"
  name: "data"
  ##type: "Input"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  transform_param {
    mean_file: "images/train_valid_lmdb_mean.binaryproto"
  }
  data_param {
    source: "images/train_valid_lmdb"
    batch_size: 1000
    backend: LMDB
  }
  input_param {
    shape {
      dim: 1
      dim: 3
      dim: 200
      dim: 200
    }
  }
}
layer {
  ##name: "input"
  name: "data"
  ##type: "Input"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  transform_param {
    mean_file: "images/train_valid_lmdb_mean.binaryproto"
  }
  data_param {
    source: "images/test_lmdb"
    batch_size: 100
    backend: LMDB
  }
  input_param {
    shape {
      dim: 1
      dim: 3
      dim: 200
      dim: 200
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 50
    kernel_size: 5
    ##stride: 5
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "conv1"
}
layer {
  name: "conv1.5"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "conv1.5"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 10
    kernel_size: 5
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu1.5"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv1.5"
  top: "conv1.5"
}
layer {
  name: "conv2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv1.5"
  top: "conv2"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 3
    kernel_size: 8
    stride: 4
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu2"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "conv2"
}
layer {
  name: "fc3"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "fc3"
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 3
  }
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "fc3"
  bottom: "label"
}
```

But the loss still does not decrease. Should I be confirmed that the cause is my dataset? And my dataset is really very small and if anyone could give me a hand, I can upload it onto somewhere a net disk to be downloaded for test.

Comment: Remove pooling layer, and try over-fitting on a small subset of data first to gauge the capability of your network.

Comment: @Ibrahim Yousuf Thank you so much! But could you please explain why should the pooling layer be removed?

Comment: Since you said the network doesn't learn. I would remove pooling layer, and try to overfit on a small subset of dataset. If it overfits, this means there's no issue with the formulation of the network.

Comment: @Ibrahim Yousuf  I have updated my post and replaced the pooling layer with a convolutional layer but of no use. Would you please follow my post?

Comment: Try the training with decreased learning rate. Start with `1e-4` maybe. Also, I would first keep the `num_output` of `conv2` the same as `conv1.5`. One other question, how did you make your dataset?

Comment: @Ibrahim Yousuf I can tell you that even with current learning rate, the changing amount a behind the 3rd digit after the decimal point!

Comment: @Ibrahim Yousuf     I have uploaded it. You can download the dataset from here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1w5GExbG1iHe44hnJtMwfl6gejy002WIF

Comment: @Ibrahim Yousuf  Have you tried my dataset?

Comment: No, but the data is single example of each class with variation is spatial dimension. And CNNs are invariant to spatial variation. So, you need more data with variation in size of geometric objects, rotation, and maybe variation in background.

Comment: @Ibrahim Yousuf  Thanks a lot! Then what deep learning model is possible to handle the task as mine? Would you please suggest that to me? Or even not deep learning models, ordinary machine learning models with no prior knowledge to the spatial structure of the dataset.

Comment: @Ibrahim Yousuf  I know it is easy to handle such task by the way as object detection methods as Faster R-CNN. But is there possibility to handle it via only CNN?

Comment: Your problem is a classification task, and yes CNN should be able to handle it. Why not you scrap images of these geometric shape from internet and make a larger dataset and then train the network.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The labels for classification should start from zero not one e.g. 0, 1 ,2 for three classification problem not 1, 2, 3.